# OpenAm redirecting to 404 after login

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, openam

After a successful login (using correct username and password) to OpenAm realm, we are greeted with a 404 The page you're looking for could not be found. while page is being redirected to    http://example.openam.com.

We are pointing to openAm configured in remote server and trying to access it through local system. It is working fine for few of my friends but other few we are getting the same problem.

I tried checking openAm log so I could only find the problem is in saying 
"naming service is not available" but same is working for other users. I tried to reconfigue entire thing from start including maven and my IDE. I am using windows environment. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of your "Default Success Login URL" field?

Comment: it is redirected to "/" default

Comment: If so, users are redirected to http://example.openam.com/. You may have to change it to the default value, "/openam/console". See also: https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam/11.0.0/admin-guide/chap-auth-services#auth-core-post-auth

Comment: I have checked that earlier. It seems fine

Comment: I am still getting the same naming service is not available error. is there any way I can bypass naming server?